# is it ok to share Apple Distribution certificate and key?

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

One of my developer is asking me to export my Apple Distribution certificate and key from my Keychain and send it to him. He claims he need this to run the app we are developing on his device. I am concerned about sharing this certificate. what should I do? is there an alternative way which does not involve sharing the certificate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developer will need the Apple Development Certificate to run and debug the application in the device. You can use TestFlight for Testing purpose but for development one will need the certificate.

If the functionalities of the application doesn't require device then the app can be used in the simulators as well.

Comment: what are the risks of sharing the certificate? would it be an alternative if I add the developer device to the list of devices in the apple developer console?

Comment: You'll need to add the device in the apple developer console anyways if the developer wants to run the application on the device.

You don't need to give a Distribution certificate; instead, give only the Apple Development Certificate which will be sufficient to run in a device.

The developer may misuse if the Distribution Certificate is given but there are very few chances of anyone doing that. So, it is better you go for a Development certificate.